# How do I format the contents of a DataGrid cell as a Date? as Currency?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, datagrid

I have a Silverlight `DataGrid` that's being populated with different types of data for each column.  I'm trying to figure out how to format some of the contents of the `DataGrid`'s cells, specifically for dates and formatting.

I have a date column that's currently displaying like: **3/11/2010 12:00:00 AM**.  I would rather it display like **3/14/2010**.

I have a number column that's currently displaying like: **51.32**. I'd rather it display as currency like **$51.32**.

I'm not sure how I can go about doing this.  I'd prefer to do it in XAML instead of C#, but both solutions are fine.

---

For reference, here's my XAML so far:

```
    </data:DataGridTextColumn>

        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Payee" 
                                 Binding="{Binding Payee}"/>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Category"
                                 Binding="{Binding Category}"/>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Memo" 
                                 Binding="{Binding Memo}"/>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Inflow" 
                                 Binding="{Binding Inflow}"/>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Outflow" 
                                 Binding="{Binding Outflow}"/>
    </data:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a IValueconverter based on string.Format and bind it in XAML.

[Check out how to do it here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx)

[Yet another article to address the same](http://silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/bindingtocontrols/)

Answer (score 5):

If you have the possibility to wait for the release of Silverlight 4, possibly at Mix10 next week. It has some new features in the binding, like formatting. With Silverlight 4 you can do stuff like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ReleaseDate, StringFormat='MMM dd, yyyy', 
                    Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Shawn Wildermuth has a nice overview of the new features on [his blog](http://wildermuth.com/2009/11/18/Data_Binding_Changes_in_Silverlight_4).